# Compare NSStrings contains Emoji characters

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, cocoa

I'm working in a function that reverse string even if it has emoji characters. The function works great in all cases. Now I'm writing test cases for this method and it passes all tests except tests that has Emoji even if the reversed string is totally correct. It seems that `isEqualToString` doesn't work properly if strings have emoji characters. Here is the Assert method:

```
- (void)doTestCase:(NSString *)test assertedValue:(NSString *)value{

    NSString *reversedString = [test reversedString];

    XCTAssert([reversedString isEqualToString:value]);
}
```

I call it like this:

```
[self doTestCase:@"LOL" assertedValue:@"LOL"];
```

but it fails even if the reversed string is totally the same.

Tried converting to UniCode like this but the same issue:

```
- (void)doTestCase:(NSString *)test assertedValue:(NSString *)value{

    NSString *reversedString = [test reversedString];

    NSData *data = [value dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *goodValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   data = [reversedString dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
   NSString *goodReversedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   XCTAssert([goodReversedString isEqualToString:goodValue]);
}
```

Comment: How are you reversing the string? NSString doesn't have a reverseString function.

Comment: It has I think but i'm building my own function for some reasons. The function works properly actually, its just about comparing results

Comment: The code of `reversedString` may be clearly useful... Is `[value dataUsingEncoding:...]` equals to `[reversedString dataUsingEncoding:...]`? Also, `LOL` is a palindrome, so it's hard to says that is has been correctly reversed or not. Could it be that just the each word are reversed, but not characters?

Comment: I printed out actually both strings, the expected and reversed one. Both are equal

Comment: What's the point of the encoding/decoding? Why not just compare `value` with `reversedString`?

Comment: @rmaddy because the obvious way didn't work

Comment: You wrote: "It seems that isEqualToString doesn't work properly if strings have emoji characters". If you try `[@"LOL" isEqualToString:@"LOL"]` what is the result? Try the other three permutations of passing `@"LOL"` and `@"LOL"`, what results do you get? They are all correct. So `isEqualToString` is not your problem. You need to look elsewhere, and if you are stuck and need help you need to edit this question and *at least* include your code to reverse strings. HTH